# Resolution difference between hardware and AVD emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, resolution, android-virtual-device

I created a simple game with a background image. I also set up a custom AVD emulator to mimic my LG G5. I gave it the same resolution, API level, screen size and manually edited the config file to set the density to 560ppi (the G5's density is 554).

With and without the custom density, the app doesn't appear and small on the phone than in the emulator. I even need to adjust the margins of the button and text (that are hidden in the screenshots I post below) in order for them to appear correct in the center of the screen on my phone.

**See here the examples:**

In the IDE (and emulator):

[image]

On my phone:

[image]

What can be the cause of this inconsistency? Is this a common side-effect?

*I saw a similar post here on SO, but the issue was the density. But after changing it to 560ppi, it didn't solve my issue.*

This is the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/won"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="159dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="125dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="125dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="resetGame"
        android:text="@string/button_play"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="425dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:rowCount="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/coin"
            android:onClick="gridClick"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/coin"
            android:onClick="gridClick"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/coin"
            android:onClick="gridClick"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/coin"
            android:onClick="gridClick"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/coin"
            android:onClick="gridClick"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/coin"
            android:onClick="gridClick"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/coin"
            android:onClick="gridClick"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/coin"
            android:onClick="gridClick"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/coin"
            android:onClick="gridClick"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the reported DPI/density on device? From this thread: https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g5/help/how-to-change-dpi-root-t3351366 and https://www.reddit.com/r/lgg5/comments/5drggj/what_is_the_stock_dpi/ it appears to default to 640dpi

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thank you for your answer. Changing it to 640 was the right solution. I based it on gsmarena specs first, but I guess using a DPI checker app is a more reliable way. It's unfortunate that the editor still shows the wrong DPI though.